# elasticsearch: how to measure index size on a cluster? (true confusion!)

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch 1.7.x on centos
3 node cluster
Config is essentially stock (out of box)

We monitor these elements from _stats

```
index.size: 94,594,769,960 bytes
index.primary_size: 67,570,017,426 bytes
```

But when we look at the OS, df -h, on any one node, it says:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      158G   48G  103G  32% /
```

So.... where are the 94 gig of indexes in index.size?

And, this is a one-index env. Why is there a delta between index.size and index.primary_size?

Essentially: How do I map the stats I see in ES to what is consumed from the OS?

Comment: 48 on a single node ?

Comment: `primary_size` is the size of the primary shards. `size` is the size of primaries + size of replicas. The `df -h` is the result for a single node?

Comment: @AndreiStefan yes, OP enhanced above